# Get IntelliJ to work with static resources in a separate module

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, multi-module

##### Goal

How do I get IntelliJ to work with a maven multi-module project where one module holds shared static resources used by other modules? By work I mean that IntelliJ can for example:

- autocomplete and automatically add import code of JavaScript classes that reside in the module that holds the shared static resources
- warn if a link to an imported static resource is incorrect

Preferably I would like to solve this using maven, and if that is not possible then using IntelliJ settings.

##### Results

If I in index.html in the **public** module write "new Mon" it suggests "Monkey" - which is a JavaScript class that resides in the **shared** module -  and if I accept this it autocompletes to "new Monkey()" but no import is added and there is a bubble that says "*Cannot build a module path for importing*".

##### What I have tried

I am fairly confident that the dependency is added correctly.

I have added the below to public module build:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>../shared/src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I invalidated caches, deleted the main iml file and restarted.

I have tried using File -> Project Structure -> Modules to add a content root to the public module.

##### Code

Two modules - **public** and **admin** - have the module **shared** as a dependency. The module **shared** holds static resources will be used by both **public** and **admin**.

Module structure:

- modules

  - logic

    - db
    - file-storage
  - sites

    - admin
    - public
    - shared
    - site-starter

The project generates a single jar that can start either the module/site **admin** or the module/site **public**. The code works fine running both in IntelliJ and as jar and can read the static resources in shared as I have set Javalin to point to it.

Here is the project:
https://github.com/Schinzel/kotlin-template-v2-multi-module

Comment: The sample project does not have a shared module in it. And it seems like the error("Cannot build a module path for importing") from the IDE is not related to maven but [the package.json file](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=%22Cannot%20build%20a%20module%20path%20for%20importing%22).

Comment: @EthanYin It now has a shared module. Sorry about that. Am at a hotel with a shaky connection so the push I did yesterday seemed to have failed.

Comment: @EthanYin 
1) package.json is an nmp file. Not something you see in a maven/IntelliJ project. So I do not think is related. 
2) Yes the error message is from the IntelliJ, but IntelliJ uses maven to set up the project. So changes in the maven configuration could definitely change the behaviour of IntelliJ and could fix the error.